# Mysterious infinite loop in Python 2.7.9 on Mac OS X 10.10.3

Tags: python, macos, infinite-loop

I wrote a Python script which solves ["Fox, goose and bag of beans puzzle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox,_goose_and_bag_of_beans_puzzle). I wrote the code in ABM(agent based model). Each thing that needs to be carried over the river is a Passenger object. Also two lands by the river are Space objects.

The code runs fine to solve the original problem. However, as soon as I try to initialize objects(e.g. peasant2, fox2) the infinite loop happens. I mean I only initialized. I never put them in the actual simulation. So if one uncomment the line num 170(#fox2 = Passenger('fox', 'rooster')), the infinite loop happens. The funny thing is that you can initialize additional grain or rooster, but not peasant or fox. I thought it might be due to random module so I tried to set seed with

```
random.seed(some_int)
```

But it didn't solve anything.

Here's the interesting part; the code works fine on Windows 10 Python 2.7.4. I've tried with another Mac but it would also have the infinite loop. 
Is it a Mac issue or Python issue? What's wrong with my codes?

**Code with no error**

```
from sets import Set
import random
from itertools import *

class Passenger(object):
  """ Anything that gets on board on the boat.
  Assumed that there could be multiple captains """
  def __init__(self, species, food=None, is_captain=False):
    self.species = species
    self.food = food
    self.is_captain = is_captain

  def eat(self, something):
    return self.food == something.species

  def __str__(self):
    return "I am %s" % self.species

class Space(object):
  """docstring for """
  def __init__(self, name, residents=[]):
    self.name = name
    self.residents = residents
    self.captains = self.update_captains()

  def num_residents(self):
    return len(self.residents)

  ## e.g. send_off([traveller1, traveller2])
  def send_off(self, passengers):
    ''' Remove the passengers who left for the other land.
    It means that the number of captains in the land is changed. '''
    self.residents = list(Set(self.residents) - Set(passengers))
    self.captains = self.update_captains()

  ## e.g. welcome([sailing_captain, traveller])
  def welcome(self, passengers):
    ''' Append newcomers '''
    self.residents += passengers
    self.captains = self.update_captains()

  def update_captains(self):
    return [r for r in self.residents if r.is_captain]

  def pick_a_captain(self):
    ''' Pick a captain randomly '''
    return random.choice(self.captains)

  def print_resident_species(self):
    ''' Simply print out every species in the land.
    For debug purpose '''
    for r in self.residents:
      print r.species

  def get_resident_species(self):
    ''' e.g. Returns "fox, grain,"
    "fox, grain, peasant" '''
    species = [r.species for r in self.residents]
    return ', '.join(species)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name + ": " + self.get_resident_species()


''' Stand-alone functions '''
def get_captains(residents):
  return [r for r in residents if r.is_captain]

def is_peaceful_pair(pair):
  ''' e.g. is_peaceful_pair([fox, rooster]) => False '''
  p1 = pair[0]
  p2 = pair[1]
  return not p1.eat(p2) and not p2.eat(p1)

def is_peaceful(residents):
  ''' e.g. is_peaceful([fox, rooster, grain]) => False '''
  for pair in list(permutations(residents, r=2)):
    if not is_peaceful_pair(pair):
      return False
  return True

def select_traveller(from_):
  for t in from_.residents:
      ## Figure out if the rest of the residents will get along
      if is_peaceful(list(Set(from_.residents) - Set([t]))):
        from_.send_off([t])
        return t
  return None

def get_sailing_captain(from_):
  sailing_captain = from_.pick_a_captain()
  from_.send_off([sailing_captain])
  return sailing_captain

## e.g. travel_to_destination(korea, japan)
## If succeeds, return passengers. If not, return None(stop the simulation)
def travel_to_destination(from_, to):
  '''
  Randomly pick one traveller and figures out whether the rest will be safe.
  Loop until find one and if not, this simulation should end.
  '''
  if len(from_.captains) == 0:
    ## No captain, no simulation
    print "There is no captain who can sail a boat :("
    return None
  sailing_captain = get_sailing_captain(from_)

  ## Shuffle the residents list so that you always get a random traveller
  random.shuffle(from_.residents)
  traveller = select_traveller(from_)
  if traveller != None:
    passengers = [sailing_captain, traveller]
    to.welcome(passengers)
    return passengers
  else:
    return None

## e.g. travel_back(japan, korea):
##
def travel_back(from_, to):
  sailing_captain = get_sailing_captain(from_)
  ## Shuffle the residents list so that you always get a random traveller
  if is_peaceful(from_.residents):
    to.welcome([sailing_captain])
    return [sailing_captain]
  else:
    traveller = select_traveller(from_)
    passengers = [sailing_captain, traveller]
    to.welcome(passengers)
    return passengers

def get_passenger_name(passengers):
  return tuple(p.species for p in passengers)

def print_land_info(lands):
  for l in lands:
    print l

peasant = Passenger('human', is_captain=True)
''' IF I UNCOMMENT THE NEXT LINE OUT, THE INFINITE LOOP HAPPENS!!! '''
#fox2 = Passenger('fox', 'rooster')
fox = Passenger('fox', 'rooster')
rooster = Passenger('rooster', 'grain')
#rooster2 = Passenger('rooster', 'grain')
grain = Passenger('grain')
#grain2 = Passenger('grain')


korea = Space('Korea', [peasant, fox, rooster, grain])
japan = Space('Japan')

POPULATION = korea.num_residents()
CAPTAIN = get_captains(korea.residents)
i = 1
while True:
  print "Loop", i
  passengers = travel_to_destination(korea, japan)
  if passengers == None:
    print "The journey can't be continued"
    break
  if japan.num_residents() == POPULATION:
    print "Everyone has crossed the river safely!"
    print_land_info([japan, korea])
    break
  else:
    print "Korea ---> Japan", get_passenger_name(passengers)
    print_land_info([japan, korea])
    passengers = travel_back(japan, korea)
    print "Japan ---> Korea", get_passenger_name(passengers)
    print_land_info([japan, korea])
    print "========================"
  i += 1
```

**Code with infinite loop**

```
from sets import Set
import random
from itertools import *

class Passenger(object):
  """ Anything that gets on board on the boat.
  Assumed that there could be multiple captains """
  def __init__(self, species, food=None, is_captain=False):
    self.species = species
    self.food = food
    self.is_captain = is_captain

  def eat(self, something):
    return self.food == something.species

  def __str__(self):
    return "I am %s" % self.species

class Space(object):
  """docstring for """
  def __init__(self, name, residents=[]):
    self.name = name
    self.residents = residents
    self.captains = self.update_captains()

  def num_residents(self):
    return len(self.residents)

  ## e.g. send_off([traveller1, traveller2])
  def send_off(self, passengers):
    ''' Remove the passengers who left for the other land.
    It means that the number of captains in the land is changed. '''
    self.residents = list(Set(self.residents) - Set(passengers))
    self.captains = self.update_captains()

  ## e.g. welcome([sailing_captain, traveller])
  def welcome(self, passengers):
    ''' Append newcomers '''
    self.residents += passengers
    self.captains = self.update_captains()

  def update_captains(self):
    return [r for r in self.residents if r.is_captain]

  def pick_a_captain(self):
    ''' Pick a captain randomly '''
    return random.choice(self.captains)

  def print_resident_species(self):
    ''' Simply print out every species in the land.
    For debug purpose '''
    for r in self.residents:
      print r.species

  def get_resident_species(self):
    ''' e.g. Returns "fox, grain,"
    "fox, grain, peasant" '''
    species = [r.species for r in self.residents]
    return ', '.join(species)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name + ": " + self.get_resident_species()


''' Stand-alone functions '''
def get_captains(residents):
  return [r for r in residents if r.is_captain]

def is_peaceful_pair(pair):
  ''' e.g. is_peaceful_pair([fox, rooster]) => False '''
  p1 = pair[0]
  p2 = pair[1]
  return not p1.eat(p2) and not p2.eat(p1)

def is_peaceful(residents):
  ''' e.g. is_peaceful([fox, rooster, grain]) => False '''
  for pair in list(permutations(residents, r=2)):
    if not is_peaceful_pair(pair):
      return False
  return True

def select_traveller(from_):
  for t in from_.residents:
      ## Figure out if the rest of the residents will get along
      if is_peaceful(list(Set(from_.residents) - Set([t]))):
        from_.send_off([t])
        return t
  return None

def get_sailing_captain(from_):
  sailing_captain = from_.pick_a_captain()
  from_.send_off([sailing_captain])
  return sailing_captain

## e.g. travel_to_destination(korea, japan)
## If succeeds, return passengers. If not, return None(stop the simulation)
def travel_to_destination(from_, to):
  '''
  Randomly pick one traveller and figures out whether the rest will be safe.
  Loop until find one and if not, this simulation should end.
  '''
  if len(from_.captains) == 0:
    ## No captain, no simulation
    print "There is no captain who can sail a boat :("
    return None
  sailing_captain = get_sailing_captain(from_)

  ## Shuffle the residents list so that you always get a random traveller
  random.shuffle(from_.residents)
  traveller = select_traveller(from_)
  if traveller != None:
    passengers = [sailing_captain, traveller]
    to.welcome(passengers)
    return passengers
  else:
    return None

## e.g. travel_back(japan, korea):
##
def travel_back(from_, to):
  sailing_captain = get_sailing_captain(from_)
  ## Shuffle the residents list so that you always get a random traveller
  if is_peaceful(from_.residents):
    to.welcome([sailing_captain])
    return [sailing_captain]
  else:
    traveller = select_traveller(from_)
    passengers = [sailing_captain, traveller]
    to.welcome(passengers)
    return passengers

def get_passenger_name(passengers):
  return tuple(p.species for p in passengers)

def print_land_info(lands):
  for l in lands:
    print l


peasant = Passenger('human', is_captain=True)
peasant2 = Passenger('human', is_captain=True)
''' IF I UNCOMMENT THE NEXT LINE OUT, THE INFINITE LOOP HAPPENS!!! '''
fox2 = Passenger('fox', 'rooster')
fox = Passenger('fox', 'rooster')
rooster = Passenger('rooster', 'grain')
#rooster2 = Passenger('rooster', 'grain')
grain = Passenger('grain')
#grain2 = Passenger('grain')


korea = Space('Korea', [peasant, fox, rooster, grain])
japan = Space('Japan')

POPULATION = korea.num_residents()
CAPTAIN = get_captains(korea.residents)
i = 1
while True:
  print "Loop", i
  passengers = travel_to_destination(korea, japan)
  if passengers == None:
    print "The journey can't be continued"
    break
  if japan.num_residents() == POPULATION:
    print "Everyone has crossed the river safely!"
    print_land_info([japan, korea])
    break
  else:
    print "Korea ---> Japan", get_passenger_name(passengers)
    print_land_info([japan, korea])
    passengers = travel_back(japan, korea)
    print "Japan ---> Korea", get_passenger_name(passengers)
    print_land_info([japan, korea])
    print "========================"
  i += 1
```

---

**Edit:**
I [updated code](http://pastebin.com/RBzWCxK3) according to @hamstergene's advice. I fixed the bug in

```
travel_back(...)
```

and added

```
__eq__ and __hash__
```

to Passenger(). However I'm not sure whether the problem is fully fixed or not yet.

Comment: just ran it on OSX and it was fine.... Python 2.7.6 / OSX 10.10.3

Comment: Yes, not able to reproduce.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Did you guys uncomment the line num 170 `#fox2 = Passenger('fox', 'rooster')`? Could you guys also add `peasant2 = Passenger('human', is_captain=True)` at line num 169 and try again?

Comment: OS X 10.10.3 - Python 2.7.6 = infinite loop (I finally stopped it when it got to 2111099) - didn't even need to uncomment the line

Comment: I too get an infinite loop, but only when I insert the `peasant2 = ...` line as well. This is a bit mysterious to me and a worthwhile question for SO. @YOUNG you might get more luck here by posting an example of code which does generate the infinite loop.

Comment: When I change the `r` value  in the line `for pair in list(permutations(residents, r=2)):` it no longer infinitely loops, but does a max of three loops

Comment: @I'L'I That's not a solution as I only need a permutation of pairs.... But thanks for the comment anyway :)

Comment: @YOUNG, I seem to get the infinite loop regardless if the line you mentioned is commented out or not. How many loops on average would this puzzle normally run?

Comment: @I'L'I 4~17 lines usually.

Comment: @YOUNG, Ironically when I uncomment the line it seems to work (average loops taken around six)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for infinite loop is a bug in your algorithm: the `travel_back` is not doing random shuffle but selects the first unsafe passenger instead. If that happens to be the one that just arrived, it becomes no-op, which gets repeated indefinitely. If you add random shuffle there, the program will always terminate:

```
def travel_back(from_, to):
  sailing_captain = get_sailing_captain(from_)
  ## Shuffle the residents list so that you always get a random traveller
  if is_peaceful(from_.residents):
    to.welcome([sailing_captain])
    return [sailing_captain]
  else:
    random.shuffle(from_.residents)  # <---
    # ....
```

The reason of 'mysterious' dependency on having an extra object created is that sets and dictionaries rely on `__hash__` and `__eq__` operations, default implementations of which (in custom classes) simply use object's memory address.

In your case allocating an extra object changes memory addresses of subsequent allocations, which in turn changes the way objects end up sorted after `list(Set(...)-Set(...))` operation in `send_off`, and affects which passenger `travel_back` will pick. Without shuffling it will always be the same object: either the good choice (no loop), or the bad one, depending on their memory addresses.

Adding the hash/equality operators will remove the mysterious dependency of having one extra object or not, and makes behavior of your program more deterministic: it will either always stuck in infinite loop (if you haven't fixed `travel_back` yet), or never:

```
class Passenger(object):
  # [...skipped...]
  def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.species == other.species
  def __hash__(self):
    return self.species.__hash__()
```

Comment: You are right about the bug in `travel_back(...)`. However, the memory address doesn't seem to be a problem in this case. I printed out the address of all the objects I created in course of time and they were never changed. So hashing shouldn't be a problem. Also even if I made my own `__hash__` and `__eq__`, the infinite loop happens "sometimes".

Comment: @YOUNG do you mean infinite loop still happens even after `travel_back` is fixed?

Comment: @hamstergene8 Now that I've upgraded to 10.10.4, I don't get any infinite loop even without a custom `__eq__`, `__hash__` or `travel_back(....)` fixed. Weird..... :\

Comment: @hamstergene8 I've made an [example code](http://pastebin.com/8hyuRAW7) to see when memory addresses might change and nothing changed. Can you elaborate on when it might be changed?

Comment: @YOUNG Memory addresses of living objects never change. In this program, numerical values of addresses themselves affect the way objects get ordered by a set, which produces semi-random behavior (either always loop, or always terminate), depending on which numbers those happened to be (depending on platform, Python version etc.)

Comment: I chose this answer because this answer seems to explain possible reasons for errors by far the best. This answer DOES NOT tell why the error happened so. However again, @hamsbergene8 made a very helpful answer.